# No current connection database error in Artifactory

Tags: connection, artifactory, derby

My Artifactory instance is running on Derby database.  Today I see a lot of errors like one below:

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No current connection

Restarting Artifactory doesn't fix the issue.  Finally, I had to empty trash and run garbage collection to get things work again - at least for now.  What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Derby is probably not the best option for your production DB. It runs in memory, competes with Artifactory over resources and is not designed to be used by very large-scaled Artifactory servers. I would recommend reading this to choose a database that might be better suited for your needs - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Database#ConfiguringtheDatabase-ChoosingtheRightDatabase

Comment: It sounds like your disk maybe was full, if emptying trash helped? If you include the complete exception output, and as much additional information as you can, maybe people could give you more suggestions. For example, can you find the Derby server log for your Derby instance?

Comment: Disk is not full.  As mentioned, empty the trash and run GC helps for now.  Basically, all internal tasks such as indexing archives fail because of this no current connection issue.